# The orientation in .jpg file is not honored in FireMonkey TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, device-orientation, twebbrowser, delphi-10.3-rio

I got help from Peter Wolf last week to rotate a photo in TWebBrowser. Now I am trying to further take the advantage of orientation. The following is a simple photo in portrait mode.  It is loaded correctly in Chrome and Edge and I can see the orientation is automatically honored. But how to make this work in FireMonkey TWebBrowser of Delphi 10.3.3. I tried some meta tags but no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    img {
      display: block;
      width: 300px;
      height: auto;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <img src="20190228-1.JPG" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't support EXIF orientation.

Comment: Since IE does not honor EXIF orientation you have to apply appropriate transformation to your image (e.g. via CSS). If you have access to image data in your Delphi code, you should be able to read orientation tag from it and then load HTML with transformed image into your `TWebBrowser`. There are also Javascript libraries that can do the same.